# JavaScript APi для того, чтобы узнать частоту слова в русском языке

Tags: javascript, теория-вероятностей, естественный-язык

Есть ли для JavaScript API или что-либо, позволяющее узнать частоту слова в русском языке?

Answer (score 2):

Есть частотные словари русского языка http://www.artint.ru/projects/frqlist.php

Можно написать серверный скрипт, который будет анализировать переданное слово и отдавать его частоту.

Answer (score 2):

Не бывает "частоту слова в языке" без уточнения "в каком именно корпусе".

Слово "аспирин" будет иметь в корпусе, составленном из текстов Пушкина нулевую частоту, а в корпусе медицинских текстов - выше среднего, чем в других корпусах. И допустим, слово "мем" не употребляли в литературе до 2000х годов, поэтому не факт, что в корпусе вам встретится этот слово. (Как вы будете обрабатывать эту ситуацию?)

Но судя по всему вам достаточно всё равно, в каком корпусе брать. Возьмите [opencorpora](http://opencorpora.org/) и сделайте сами к нему нужное API, как вам нравится.

В этом корпусе собран достаточно современный русский язык, в т.ч. из интернета.